# OrleansHost.exe fails to start Silo when using AzureTableStorage provider

Tags: orleans

I am an Orleans newbie and trying to work through the excellent tutorials from the main Orleans site.

I am up to the Declarative Persistence example and having trouble getting it to work. I suspect I am missing a configuration setting, and would appreciate some guidance (I can attach my solution if required).

I have setup the solution as per the Employee/Manager example using the templates from Orleans Tools for VS (v1.2.0). The solution has a Grains project (holding the grains, the state objects, and the orleans host configuration file), an interfaces project (grain interfaces and common objects), and a Silo project (sets up the grains and interacts with them).  The Grains project starts up OrleansHost.exe and the Silo project prompts to start once the host has started up.  The OrleansConfiguration.xml file (in the Grains project) has a StorageProviders section (under Globals) and I have 2 provider types: Orleans.Storage.MemoryStorage (MemoryStore) and Orleans.Storage.AzureTableStorage (AzureStore).  If I remove the table storage provider the OrleansHost.exe runs  fine (last logged message is that the silo is running).

The issue I am having is when the table storage provider is included in the configuration file, the OrleansHost.exe stops logging as soon as it logs the line advising it is using the Azure Table Storage provider ("AzureTableStorage Provider is using DataConnectionString: UseDevelopmentStorage=true").  The storage table 'OrleansGrainState' is created but is never populated.  If I try and intialise a GrainFactory (by continuing the Silo execution) I get the exception: Orleans.Runtime.SiloUnavailableException, which is consistent with the OrleansHost.exe not having finished starting. The host does continue to log collection messages every minute though.

I believe I have followed the step-by-step instructions correctly, and have looked through the other posts on this site and whilst this did enable me to fix my configuration file, I still cannot get the host to start the silo so I can test the state persistence mechanism.  I have also looked through the Orleans community and contributions sites to no avail.

I am running this in VS 2015, the Orleans libraries are v1.2.0, I have the Orleans Tools for VS installed (v1.2.0), and have Azure SDK v2.9.1 installed.

I would be grateful for any assistance as I would like to continue learning about Orleans.

Thanks

Comment: UseDevelopmentStorage=true this means that you're using Azure Storage Emulator. Do you have latest Azure SDK (2.9.x) installed ? Can you verify that Azure Storage Emulator was initialized and runs on your machine without issues ?

Comment: Hi Alexey.  Yes I have the latest Azure SDK installed and the emulator is showing as running on the machine.  The storage table called OrleansGrainState is created and I can open it but it contains nothing.

Comment: I'm not yet sure what could be the cause. Have you tried to run silo directly inside your worker role, not using OrleansHost.exe ? I suspect that OrleansHost may not play well with latest nugets...
Also there is a known incompartibility issue with latest 7.1.2 WindowsAzure.Storage nuget - if you're updated your nuget to latest 7.1.2  - please revert it to 7.0.0.
I feel that it might be easier to diagnose this specific problem in a real-time chat, so I'd like to invite you to Orleans community chat here https://gitter.im/dotnet/orleans

Comment: Hi Alexey.  I think you are right about the OrleansHost because I have just got it to work by running the silo directly inside the worker role and am now seeing both the silo starting and data being written into storage as expected.  Can't believe I did not try this first.  Thank you for your help, and I will certainly take note of your comments about the nuget packages (not that this applied in this instance though).